# How do I use the function in the class below in the other class without using global

Tags: python

How do I use the function in the class below in the other class without using global?
Code:

```
class one:
    class one_one:
        def add(x):
            return x+1
    class one_two:
        ans = one.one_one.add(1)
```

Comment: Your class definition makes no sense. Why are you nesting classes like this to begin with? your method, `add` is not defined correctly either, the first argument should be `self` which will be passed the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is an unusual design, but it will work if you remember to distinguish between classes and instances of classes (objects).  In your example you are attempting to call `add` in the class `one_one` which is an instance method without first instantiating an object of that class type.  The example below shows one way to achieve what you are trying to do by instantiating the objects before calling their methods.

Example:

```
class one:
    class one_one:
        def add(self, x):
            return x+1
    class one_two:
        def add(self):
          a_one_one = one.one_one()
          ans = a_one_one.add(1)
          return ans

a_one_two = one.one_two()
print(a_one_two.add())
```

Output:

```
2
```